# displaying mysql datetime in nvd3 line chart

Tags: javascript, php, d3.js

I am creating a json using php query from database and I want to display the datetime returned from the table in the nvd3 chart. Here is the sample json that I am getting:

```
[
  {
    "key": "series1",
    "values": [
      {
        "date_time": "2014-08-31 08:35:01",//1409474101
        "rate": 10
      },
      {
        "date_time": "2014-08-31 09:00:02",//1409475602
        "rate": 10
      },
      {
        "date_time": "2014-08-31 10:00:01",//1409479201
        "rate": 6
      },
      {
        "date_time": "2014-08-31 11:00:01",//1409482801
        "rate": 7
      },
      {
        "date_time": "2014-08-31 12:00:01",//1409486401
        "rate": 6
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and here is my script:

```
<script>
nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.lineWithFocusChart();

  chart.xAxis
  .axisLabel("Date Time")
    .tickFormat(function(d) {
          return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d))
      });
    ;

  chart.yAxis
    .axisLabel("Rate")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));

  chart.y2Axis
    .tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));

  d3.select('#chart svg')
    .datum(data())
    .transition().duration(500)
    .call(chart)
    ;
  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

  return chart;
});


/*============================Data===========================*/

function data() {
  var retData = <?php echo $json_data; ?>;

  return retData;
}

</script>
```

but my graph is not getting plotted all I get is a single line chart with x axis labels as "1-1-1970"

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? Did you verify that the data is parsed correctly?

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff I looked into the console but there is no error, and I don't think the  data is being parsed, what am I doing wrong? :(

Comment: If your data is exactly like in the example you've posted, it's probably the comments that are confusing it.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff yes, the json data is exactly the same I am getting from querying the table, those comments just represent the timestamp, I have removed it but then too the graph is not getting plotted, can you give me an example on how to do this? thanks for your reply

Comment: Ah, you need to use the proper format specifier for your dates, see https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting

Comment: @LarsKotthoff no luck, this is the graph I am getting: http://i.stack.imgur.com/wvDR3.png

in tickformat for x axis I have added `d3.time.format('%c')(new Date(d))`